# Efficient method to index this many MongoDB data, or change scheme?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, schema

I have data that include so many fields and are need to be queried like this:

name / marker1 / marker2 / ... / marker500k -- these are fields

A1231 / GG / CT / ... / TT -- each one is a document = {'name':'A1231', 'marker1':'GG, 'marker2':'CT', ...}

B3435 / GC / CT / ... / TA

Z4463 / CC / TT / ... / AA

Queries are expected to be these ones:

1) How about the statistics for marker1,2,100,150,3000?

Answer is marker1: GG 100, GC 150, CC 80, marker2: something, etc.

2) What names do have marker123155:AA?

Annwer is 11 documents, and they are D13414, E31341, etc.

It's so slow, there are many fields (hundred Ks) and many documents (currently tens Ks).

If "markers" are to be indexed, then I should change them into SQL-like "name", "marker#", "type"? Otherwise, is there a better way to model using MongoDB?

current:

{'name':'A1231', 'marker1':'GG, 'marker2':'CT', ... , 'marker3':'TT'}

to-be:

{'name':'A1231', 'marker':'marker1', 'type':GG'},
{'name':'A1231', 'marker':'marker2', 'type':CT'},
... ,
{'name':'A1231', 'marker':'marker500k', 'type':'TT'}

Any tips or comments very appreciated.

Comment: Thank you a lot. That's a simple way but I just had missed. I would try this one. BTW, The compound index is enough for not only query for both field but also for query for single field? Otherwise, I need additional indexing to "markers" only?

Comment: Please tell if each document has 500,000 markers populated _or_ only some of the marker fields are populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your schema such that the top-level document contains an array of `marker` documents, like so

```
{
   name: "A1231",
   markers: [
       {
           number: 1,
           tag: "GG"
       },
       {
           number: 2,
           tag: "CT"
       }
       ...
   ]
}
```

Then you can create an index on `markers.number`, `markers.tag`, and a compound index on both of them.

Comment: We could start from your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> If "markers" are to be indexed, then I should change them into
> SQL-like "name", "marker#", "type"? Otherwise, is there a better way
> to model using MongoDB?
>
> current: { 'name': 'A1231', 'marker1': 'GG', 'marker2': 'CT', ... ,
> 'marker3': 'TT' }
>
> to-be: { 'name': 'A1231', 'marker': 'marker1', 'type': GG' },  {
> 'name': 'A1231', 'marker': 'marker2', 'type': CT' },  ... ,  { 'name':
> 'A1231', 'marker': 'marker500k', 'type': 'TT' }

Here are some comments on this "to-be" model (as posted in the question post):

The number of documents is going to be about 5 billion - quite large.

**(i) 'marker': 'marker1':**

I suggest, change this field definition to `marker: 1`, where the number `1` is the `marker1`, `2` is `marker2`, etc. The number value occupies less storage and is faster to search on. Since, there is going to be an index on the `marker` field to support the queries, the size of the index also reduces with using the numeric value. The index size matters, as a large sized index may not be able load into the memory totally for its proper usage.

**(ii) First query:**

> How about the statistics for marker1, 2, 100, 150, 3000?
>
> Answer is marker1: GG 100, GC 150, CC 80, marker2: something, etc.

With the new design, the index will be on the `{ marker: 1, type: 1 }`, a compound index. Since, this query has grouping, this will be an aggregation query. For an aggregation query to use an index the match stage must come early or first; then only the index will be used.

The aggregation query will have the `$match` stage to select markers specified, and followed by the `$group` stage (grouping on `marker`+`type` and counting).

**(ii) Second query:**

> What names do have marker123155: AA?
>
> Answer is 11 documents, and they are D13414, E31341, etc.

This will be a simple find query: `db.test.find( { marker: 123155, type: "AA" } )`.
This query will also use the same index, mentioned above in the first query.

---

This is **another idea** about designing the schema:

**(i) Grouping of documents:**

*From this (5 billion documents):*

```
{ 'name': 'A1231', 'marker': 'marker1', 'type': GG' }, 
{ 'name': 'A1231', 'marker': 'marker2', 'type': CT' },
 ... , 
{ 'name': 'A1231', 'marker': 'marker500k', 'type': 'TT' }
```

*To (fewer documents):*

Use a bucketing concept. That is for each `name` we will have about 10 buckets; this is a grouping of the `marker`s by their number (1 to 500000). There are 500,000 markers for each name. We will have about 10 groups for each `name` and the model will be like below with 50,000 markers per group (note the new `group`field):

```
{ name: "A11", group: 50000, markers: [ { marker: 1, type: "GG" }, { marker: 2, type: "CT" }, ..., { marker: 50000, type: "GG" } ] },
{ name: "A11", group: 100000, markers: [ { marker: 50001, type: "GC" }, ..., { marker: 100000, type: "CC" } ] },
..., ...,
{ name: "A11", group: 500000, markers: [ { marker: 450001, type: "AA" }, ..., { marker: 500000, type: "TA" } ] }
```

**(ii) The first query:**

> How about the statistics for marker1, 2, 100, 150, 3000?
>
> Answer is marker1: GG 100, GC 150, CC 80, marker2: something, etc.

An example, selecting the markers 25, 1890, 12456 and 495000. These markers fall under the groups 50000 and 500000. The query will look like this:

```
db.test.aggregate( [
 { $match: { group: { $in: [ 50000, 500000 ] } } },
 { $unwind: "$markers" },
 { $match: { "markers.marker": { $in: [ 25, 1890, 12456, 495000 ] } } },
 { $group: { _id: { m: "$markers.marker", t: "$markers.type" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
] )
```

To select documents by the groups we will create a compound index: `{ group: 1, marker: 1, type: 1 }`. The aggregation query will use the index in the match stages.

On a small sample set of data, the query plan showed that the query runs with an index scan, uses the defined index (the query plan was generated using the `explain()`).

**(iii) Second query:**

> What names do have marker123155: AA?
>
> Answer is 11 documents, and they are D13414, E31341, etc.

This will be a simple find query: `db.test.find( { group: 100000, markers: { $elemMatch: { marker: 123155, type: "AA" } } } )`
This query also uses the same index, `{ group: 1, marker: 1, type: 1 }`, and a generated query plan shows that.

**NOTES:**

This is about the grouping. The figure of 50,000 documents per group is an idea. The number of documents per group can be less or more; e.g., like 25,000 or 10,000 or 100,000. This is to be determined based upon some trials and how the performance benefits.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Actually the "array" method was great but in terms of performance, as some basic queries spent about three seconds, we hope we could reduce it. Now we're trying to transform the structure to use numbers for storage effectivity, which might lead to better speed. And the idea 'grouping' also looks nice. It would be able to skip nonrelevant documents then might cost less, the run time.